# Почему работает этот код, несмотря на стирание типов?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Solution<T extends HashMap> {
    private T map;

    public Solution(T map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public T getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("string", 4);
        Solution solution = new Solution(hashMap);
        HashMap mapFromSolution = solution.getMap();
        System.out.println(mapFromSolution.getClass());


        LinkedHashMap<Solution, Solution> hashMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        hashMap2.put(solution, solution);
        Solution<LinkedHashMap> solution2 = new Solution(hashMap2);
        LinkedHashMap mapFromSolution2 =  solution2.getMap();   // no need to cast
        System.out.println(mapFromSolution2.getClass());
    }
}
```

Почему `solution2.getMap()` возвращает `LinkedHashMap` без приведения типа? Разве из-за стирания типов метод не должен возвращать объекты `HashMap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стирание типов происходит во *время выполнения*, а не при компиляции, поэтому компилятор ещё будет "знать", что при объявлении

```java
Solution<LinkedHashMap> solution2 = new Solution(hashMap2);
```

переменная `solution2` будет "типизирована" типом `LinkedHashMap`, несмотря на то, что в правой части будет создан "сырой" экземпляр `Solution` (о чём будет выдано соответствующее предупреждение компилятора).

Вот если бы `solution2` сразу была объявлена как истинно-"сырая" (без указания обобщённого типа), тогда можно было получить желаемую ошибку времени компиляции.
Также, несмотря на "сырость", при создании экземпляра `Solution` всё равно потребуется использовать экземпляр `HashMap` или его подкласса.

```java
Solution treeSolution = new Solution(new TreeMap()); // error: incompatible types: TreeMap cannot be converted to HashMap

// полностью сырое объявление, Т = HashMap
Solution solution2 = new Solution(hashMap2);
LinkedHashMap mapFromSolution2 =  solution2.getMap(); // error: incompatible types: HashMap cannot be converted to LinkedHashMap
```

и тогда потребовалось бы применить приведение типов для метода `getMap`:

```java
Solution solution2 = new Solution(hashMap2);
LinkedHashMap mapFromSolution2 =  (LinkedHashMap) solution2.getMap(); // ok
```

---

Ещё один пример, когда объявление мапы типизировано, но создаётся "сырая" мапа и "сырая" ссылка-псевдоним на мапу:

```java
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap();

hashMap.put("string 3", 3);
// compile error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
// hashMap.put(1, "string 1");

HashMap rawAlias = hashMap;

rawAlias.put(4, "string 4"); // типы ключа/значения не играют роли

// у сырого псевдонима всё хорошо
rawAlias.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));

// у типизированного оригинала рантайм-проблема: ClassCastException
hashMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

Вывод:

```
4 -> string 4
string 3 -> 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Почему `solution2.getMap()` возвращает `LinkedHashMap` без приведения типа?

Собственно, потому же, почему, например, метод `get()` для `List<String>` возвращает объекты типа `String`, для `List<Car>` - объекты типа `Car` и так далее.

Вот в этой строке

```
Solution<LinkedHashMap> solution2 = new Solution(hashMap2);
```

вы явным образом указываете, что при работе с `solution2` типом `T` будет являться `LinkedHashMap`. Так что `T`, как и должно, отовсюду подменяется на `LinkedHashMap`, в том числе и в методе `get()`.

И поэтому когда вы получаете геттером мапу, вам выдаётся в точности объект типа `LinkedHashMap`.

Можете попробовать даже сделать так:

```
String abc = solution2.getMap();
```

Вы увидите, что среда разработки справедливо ругается: мол метод возвращаемым типом имеет `LinkedHashMap`, а мы пытаемся его результат присвоить строке. Такой код не запустится. Ведь подстановка типов происходит ещё на этапе компиляции.

Обобщения для того и нужны: избавить программиста от излишнего приведения типов, и ошибки, связанные с неправильным использованием типов, перенести с этапа выполнения на этап компиляции.